# BaseController delegate not working in all inherited view controllers inside tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I'm having a tough time understanding why my delegates defined in base controller not working in the inherited view controllers.

I've a TabBarController which has 2 ViewControllers. Each ViewController is a subclass of BaseController.

BaseController implements a delegate and updates a label view.

When I launch the app and click Play, FirstVC updates label, but when I switch tab to SecondVC, it starts to update but when I click FirstVC again, the update is stuck and wont update the label, but the label keeps updating in SecondVC.

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

protocol SharedPlayerNotificaions : class {

    func willPlay(status: Bool)
    func currentPlayTime(timeString: String)
}

class SharedPlayer : NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = SharedPlayer()    
    private var player : AVPlayer?
    weak var delegate : SharedPlayerNotificaions?

    override private init() {
        super.init()
        player = AVPlayer()

    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if keyPath == "status" {

            if player?.status == AVPlayerStatus.Unknown {
                delegate?.willPlay(false)
            }
            if player?.status == AVPlayerStatus.Failed {
                print("failed")
                delegate?.willPlay(false)
            }

            if player?.status == AVPlayerStatus.ReadyToPlay {
                print("readytoplay")
                delegate?.willPlay(true)
            }
        }
        if keyPath == "rate" {
        }
        if keyPath == "duration" {   
        }
    }

    func play(){

        player?.play()
        let interval = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 2)
        player?.addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval(interval, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue(), usingBlock: { (progressTime) in
            let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(progressTime)
            let secondsString = String(format: "%02d", Int(seconds % 60))
            let minutesString = String(format: "%02d", Int(seconds / 60))
            self.delegate?.currentPlayTime("\(minutesString):\(secondsString)")
        })
    }

    func setUrl(urlString: String){

        if let url = NSURL(string: urlString){
            player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
            player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
             player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
             player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "duration", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

BaseController

```
    class BaseController : UIViewController, SharedPlayerNotificaions {

        let label = UILabel()

        override func viewDidLoad() {

            SharedPlayer.sharedInstance.delegate = self

            view.addSubview(label)
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))
            view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 50))
            view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))

            label.text = "00:00"
        }


   func currentPlayTime(timeString: String) { 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
        self.label.text = timeString
    }
}

        func willPlay(status: Bool) {

        }
}
```

FirstViewController

```
class FirstViewController: BaseController {


    @IBAction func playButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        let urlString = "https://someStreamUrl"

        SharedPlayer.sharedInstance.setUrl(urlString)
        SharedPlayer.sharedInstance.play()

      }

}
```

SecondViewController

```
class SecondViewController : BaseController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .redColor()
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The major flaw is that `SharedPlayer` is a singleton. There is only one instance. It can only have one delegate. But you create two view controllers. Both attempt to tell the single shared `SharedPlayer` instance that it is the delegate. The second one wins.

The delegate pattern only works when there is one delegate. In this case you have two so you can't use the traditional delegate pattern.

There are a few possible solutions.

1. Update `SharedPlayer` to accept an array of delegates instead of a single delegate.
2. Use `NSNotificationCenter`. Have `SharedPlayer` post notifications and have each view controller register for each possible notification.

Comment: Thank you, I selected your answer as correct. But, if I may ask can you please help me with a better design? I'm trying to build a MusicPlayer app where the basecontroller has a player view and inside my tabBarController all VC inherit from that, and I'm just trying to build the app from learning everything off the internet.

Comment: Why is `SharedPlayer` a singleton? Why do you want to the same `AVPlayer` in multiple tabs? Why can't each tab have its own player?

Comment: SharedPlayer is a singleton because I need to use this player to play multiple songs, and if I click next or previous song it should work, also when I change tabs, the playerview will be updated based on the avplayer else how do I update the view ?